# Out of memory with simple calc?

Tags: perl

I'm getting `out of memory` with a very simple calc.

I'm try to calc ow many topologies a binary tree might has given a number `n` of samples

So I simple try `perl -E 'sub fac{ my ($n) = @_; $n == 1 ? 1 : $n * fac($n -1)} sub top{ my ($n) = @_; $t = fac(2 * $n - 5) / (2 ** ($n - 3) * fac($n - 3) ) } say top(3)'` 
Also, a other version of same math:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
#use features;

sub factorial{
        my ($n) = @_;
        $n == 1 ? 1 : $n * factorial($n -1)
}

sub topologies{
        my ($n) = @_;
        my $a = (2 * $n) - 5;
        my $a_f = factorial($a);
        my $b = $n -3;
        my $b_f = factorial($b);
        my $c = 2 ** $b;
        my $q = $c * $b_f;
        my $t = $a_f / $q;
        return $t;
}

print "Enter number of taxas: ";
my $input = <STDIN>;
my $ntop = topologies();

print $ntop, "\n";
```

And when I try even for a sample size `3`. I got `out of memory` in a computer with 4GB of ram and 4GB of cache. The same to a 128GB or ram server.

I do not need this calc, I was just try for fun.
But I cannot figure out why I'm getting this `out of memory` message.

EDIT: I just get it when the sample is equal or smaller than 3

Comment: Hint: what happens when `$n <= 0` in the `factorial` sub?

Comment: @mob actually is expected never have `$n < 1` anyway if `$n == 0` it will return 0, and of course follows the same logic of any mathematical operation. Decreasing to lower than `0` the result should away return `0`. Anyway I understand that is better use `$n <= 1` in `sub fac` routine. So: `sub fac{ my ($n) = @_; $n <= 1 ? 1 : $n * fac($n -1)}`

Comment: Note: If you're using a 32-bit build of Perl, the maximum amount of memory the process can use is 2-3 GiB (depending on the OS), regardless of how much RAM the machine has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `$n = 3` your `toplogies(3)` will call `factorial(1)` and `factorial(0)`. The latter one is improperly implemented and tries to create the factorial by calling `factorial(-1)` which then calls `factorial(-2)` which then calls `factorial(-3)` ..., i.e. an endless recursion where each step allocates more memory. This endless recursion will result  therefore in the out of memory. Similar things happen with `$n<3`.

Comment: Thanks. So it was bad implemented, better do `sub fac{ my ($n) = @_; $n == 1 ? 1 : $n * fac($n -1)}`.